# Find location on Windows Mobile 5

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, geolocation, gps, windows-mobile-gps

I'm trying to get a Windows Mobile 5 PDA to give me its location.

It doesn't have GPS but I found [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd938890.aspx#AccessingCellTowerInformationonyourWindowsMobileDevice) that explains how to do it using cell tower information.  The example does a p/invoke to RIL.DLL, but I'm not sure if that is available on WM5, if it is I'm not sure where to find it?

Any good hints or links would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Search the http://forum.xda-developers.com/ forums. They have excellent info regarding hacking Windows Mobile devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RIL.dll is available only on phone devices.  If your WinMo PDA is a phone edition then it should be there (in the \Windows folder, probably hidden).  The remote file viewer should be able to show it, but if you simply try to P/Invoke it, you'll find out quickly if it's there or not.

Comment: You would of thought i might have checked if it was a phone device before posting this question... d'oh!